# Can I send more arguments in return Redirect::to() in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a register form on my project in Laravel 4, and when I do the register, I'm redirected to the login page. Also, my view detects when the user reached the login page from the register page and show a message to thank him.
I would like to send one more data (the e-mail address he inserted in the register form) to fill the email field (the username is the email address).

The code on the controller is like:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withMessage('<h3 style="color: #FFFFFF;">message here</h3>');
```

And I would like to do something like that:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withData('email', $data['email'])->withMessage('<h3 style="color: #FFFFFF;">message here</h3>');
```

Is that possible?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that can be done, but you have to change it a little bit.

Either use:

```
->withData(array('email' => $data['email']))
```

Or:

```
->withEmail($data['email']);
```

And here's how you retrieve it:

```
$email = Session::get('data.email');
```

Or:

```
$email = Session::get('email');
```